# Get one value from Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to get a name from a database and print it on a page. The name is in a database table together with the username. The username is accessible from the session. I'm trying it like this:

```
<?php

include('checksession.php');
require('db-connection.php');

function getUsername(){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];


    $sql = "SELECT NAME FROM benutzer WHERE BENUTZERNAME LIKE '" . $username . "'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    echo "<p>" $res "</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is open to SQL Injection.  You'll want to look into using prepared statements with query parameters.  Currently you're executing input *as code*, which allows users to arbitrarily execute code on your database.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800559/read-single-value-from-database-and-save-it-in-variable/32800580#32800580

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM benutzer WHERE BENUTZERNAME = '" . $username . "'";
```

Instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM benutzer WHERE BENUTZERNAME LIKE '" . $username . "'";
```

if you want to retrieve the exact username.

Comment: If you do that, be always careful with SQL Injection. Always use **mysqli_real_escape_string** or similar

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns an [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. You have to call one of the mysqli_result methods to get what you want to return from the DB.